# How to replace a String which has escape sequence inside a File using Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, string

how to replace a String inside a File using perl ?

```
perl -pi -e 's/Arun/Brun/g' *
```

this worked fine for me

but when i tried to change `class/students/a` to `class1/students1/B` it throws error how to solve this problem ..i tried adding back slash (`\`) before every (`/`) but it didn't help

```
perl -pi -e 's/class/students/a/class1/students1/B/g' *
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are using `/` as regex delimiter.
There are `/` even in your *pattern* and *replacement*. You need to somehow ensure that these `/` should not be treated as delimiter.

You have two options:

1. Escape the `/` in your *pattern* and *replacement* as:

   ```
   perl -pi -e 's/class\/students\/a/class1\/students1\/B/g' *
   ```
2. Or use a different delimiter:

   ```
   perl -pi -e 's#class/students/a#class1/students1/B#g' *
   ```

Method 2 is preferred as it keeps your regex *short* and *clean*.

Comment: `perl -i -e` wont update any file in-place. See perldoc perlrun

Comment: @eugene y: Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 8):

Try `perl -pi -e 's{class/students/a}{class1/students1/B}g' *`

From [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators):

> Any non-whitespace delimiter may
>   replace the slashes. Add space after
>   the s when using a character allowed
>   in identifiers. (...) If the
>   PATTERN is delimited by bracketing
>   quotes, the REPLACEMENT has its own
>   pair of quotes, which may or may not
>   be bracketing quotes, e.g.,
>   s(foo)(bar) or s/bar/.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you perldoc perlop:

My problem is changin Oracle Home has solve by your command. one more trick I have done to replace with shell variable.

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/oracle/product/11.2.0.3/db_1

perl -pi -e 's{REPLACEWITHORACLEHOME}{'$ORACLE_HOME'}g' filename
```

more scripted way is :

```
for y in `ls`;do perl -pi -e 's{REPLACEWITHORACLEHOME}{'$ORACLE_HOME'}g' $y;done
```